# Can I use multiple vendors?

Tags: open-telemetry

Can the following scenario work?

1. Vendor FOO has their own distribution of the instrumentation SDK for exporting OpenTelemetry signals to their own backend. Using their SDK would mean I get access to features A on their SaaS platform, which I'm interested in.
2. Vendor BAR has a similar-but-different distribution - also using OpenTelemetry to send data to their own backend, which would give access to me feature B on their SaaS.

**Question:** Can I instrument my app with both of their packages, and have my app export signals to each of their respective backends?   Or do I have to stick with a single vendor?

Put differently, are the OpenTelemetry SDKs isolated enough for this scenario, so that they can play nice with each other?

Comment: If their "distribution" sets the SDK I _think_ you are stuck with that. But if you set the SDK yourself, you can then have multiple exporters one for each back-end. Usually the usefulness of such SDK distros is the vendor making configuration/setting up easier for you.

Comment: Given you want to export to both, I'd probably go with the route of not using their distributions and configuring two exports myself.  You will have to exchange the easy-of-configuration with the control/more flexibility.

Comment: Uri, I'm part of the Governing Board for OTel, and I'm interested in hearing more about your case. We want to ensure that OTel distributions (agents or collectors) play nicely with the ecosystem. When you say SDK, did you mean agents? If you prefer to share concrete details over a private message, ping me on CNCF's Slack.

Comment: Thanks everyone.
@jpkroehling - will DM you there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't overinstrument app code. I would rather stick with standard OTEL lib (to have vendor neutral lib) in the app code and use local OTEL collecor, which will be exporting signals to the final vendors FOO, BAR (you can export the same signals to both). Any change of provider will be simple OTEL collector config change, no app code change.

Comment: While I agree with your point, not everyone can/want to have collectors. Vendor-provided distributions/wrappers offer a nice way to "hide" all vendor-specific configurations on the SDK (metrics temporality, sampling, export interval, authorization, URLs etc) from the user and usually becomes a very pleasant experience with just a "one-liner". But I agree, if the OP wants to send to both vendors, they should use the vanilla SDK and just configure multiple exporters.